# Remove array index based on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have array1 of shape (69316, 5, 5, 28) and array2 of length 10050. I want to remove elements from array2 for indices `0:len(array1)`. However, I have tried:

```
array3 = np.delete(array1, array2, axis=0)
```

Which throws an error (yes, I am upgrading to Python 3 next week):

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: in the future out of bounds indices will raise an error instead of being ignored by `numpy.delete`.
```

and the result I get is:

```
(67971, 5, 5, 28)
```

which I want

```
(69316 - 10050) = 59266 --> (59266, 5, 5, 28)
```

Therefore, how do I loop through an array of indices I want to delete, without improper indexing after it has been deleted, keeping only the indices which are not within array2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out -

```
array3 = array1[10050:, :, :, :]
```

Here, I'm saving only the elements after index 10050, keeping the other dimensions intact.